# Which lifecycle method to use for auth flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a simple react app with auth flow and navigation with react-router dom. The auth flow I am trying to build is when the user is authenticated he is redirecting to the /dashboard path if not to the /login.

For the auth, I am using node API with google OAuth 2 passport strategy.
I have a redux action that send the request to my server and then I am dispatching to the reducer.

I am success get user info but the problem is here.

When launching the app render directly the router and at this time she doesn't have the user info so we are not redirecting to the /dashboard, but after the action called the app have the user info but no re-render the page

here is my code

AppRouter.js

```
const AppRouter = ({fetchUser,auth}) => {

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
}, []);

console.log("App Router Signed in " ,auth);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to={auth ? '/dashboard' : '/login'}/>}/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" ><DashboardLayout/></PrivateRoute>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )


};

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
    return { auth };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser())
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppRouter);
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter/>
    </Provider>
);
  }
}
export default App;
```

You can also have a look on my google console you will see I am first getting auth = null but after auth is equal to my user object

Maybe I need to use different LifeCycle methods?

[image: Google Console]